# Can any third-party load embedded resources from my project?

Tags: security, delphi, embedded-resource

Please refer to one of my [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681364/issues-passing-data-from-dll-to-application). I'm asking about loading a compiled resource from a DLL. Then refer to the answer by David Heffernan. His suggestion is to use a built-in mechanism to load a resource directly from the DLL's instance, without even using my own exported function. This pointed out a security loophole to me.

If this is really the case, if this type of solution is possible, then can any outside third-party load resources from any Delphi Application/DLL? How secure are embedded resources? Suppose I compile a DLL with an embedded resource. Can someone take this DLL and extract the resource? How easy is it, considering they must know the resource name? Are they able to detect what resources are compiled and get a listing of named resources? If this is so, then I will have to implement my own level of security and encrypt every embedded resource and decrypt it with login.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *resource section* of a [Windows Portable Executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) is accessible and enumerable to any process/user with read privileges over the executable file.

The Windows API provide a series of functions to [work with resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), including functions to:

- Adding, Deleting, and Replacing Resources
- Enumerating Resources
- Finding and Loading Resources
- Resource File Formats
- Using Resources

In fact there's plenty of ready tools to perform this operations. Your own Delphi installation have a demo project called Resource Explorer, usually installed in the folder `Samples\Delphi\VCL\resXplor`.

As you can see, anyone with the knowledge and/or [tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=resource+editor) can not only read, but delete and replace the resources found in your windows executable, regardless of the compiler that produced it.

You can find more information about the PE file format in the article [An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I suspected. I will need to change my approach and encrypt everything I embed.

Comment: On a side-note, I never knew that embedded resources were windows-wide. I always thought it was Delphi-specific. This opened my eyes to many things.

Comment: @JerryDodge: You should see [Resource Explorer](http://melander.dk/reseditor). The app is fairly useful, and the page lists the types of resources that it can read from **any** Windows executable (which includes DLLs). You should use it to look at any Delphi app, and check the `RCDATA` resources; I think you'll be a little *surprised* at the least.

Comment: @KenWhite Understood, now that I know this is a Windows-level functionality rather than just Delphi. I mean I was sure already that about any language had a way to embed resources, but now I know it's universal for any language.

Comment: @JerryDodge: The app at the link I posted allows you to view the types of info others can see in your exe/dll (some of them visually). As I said, you might want to inspect your own application or DLL with it, so you'll know what's there you might need to protect. It works on other (non-Delphi) apps as well, some of which have some interesting resources.

Comment: @JerryDodge If you are worried about people extracting resources from your exe/dll you might also look at copy protection software suites (like Armadillo, Software Passport's protection engine) and then use a "permanent evaluation" license (without expiry) to protect the exe's and dll's of your software. This will take care of wrapping and encrypting your stuff and decrypting and unwrapping when someone starts it.

Comment: @JerryDodge there are also other tools to make it difficult to extract resources such as UPX, ASPack (Executable Packers). I think these basically compress the resources in the exe and change the internal structure of the executable making it harder (though likely not impossible) for conventional tools to process/extract data.

Comment: We used to use a HASP key from Aladdin, it wrapped the compiled EXE's and required a server dongle to be able to work. That was some great protection, but we moved away from that and are now implementing our own methods of encryption.